# Compiler error reads "end of file expected"

Tags: c#, syntax-error

The last two curly brackets on this code are underlined with an error that reads:

> type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected.

I think that my curly brackets are somehow uneven or mismatched somewhere.  I have looked through them and cannot seem to find where they are off.

```
public partial class Add_Customer : Form
{
    public Customer NewCustomer { get; set; }

    public Add_Customer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ValidateForm();
    }

    private bool ValidateForm();
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("First name is required");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: I see a return-value missing error there, but assuming you are in a namespace, the curlys look okay. Make sure `ValidateForm` will always return a value and then try rebuilding.

Comment: @GrantWinney That woulnd't be extra if there was a namespace declaration (which there should be). Assuming a namespace, I count the right number of braces.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means you have mismatched parenthesis or brackets. In your case you have an extra `}` in your method:

```
private bool ValidateForm();
{ // 1
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFirstName.Text))
        { // 2
            MessageBox.Show("First name is required");
            return false;
        } // 2
    } // <-- EXTRA!
} //1
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not a programmer but the last two seems to be extra unless you wanted the other 2 in the beginning to be not closed. Edit: Try to use an editor that highlights the blocks. Thx to Bradley woodhole comment. Besides by definition I was still correct because I did not suggest to use BlueJ Bradley, I simply said it highlights the blocks {}.

Comment: Why are you recommending a Java IDE for a C# program?